# How to check if my WHERE query is correct in Android Studio

Tags: java, database, sqlite, where-clause

I'm trying my rawQuery but my app keeps crashing and there's no error when I ran the app.

My query runs well on DB browser for SQLite.

My databasehelper:

```
public Cursor setData(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + NUMBER + " = " + id;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        return cursor;
    }
```

My MainActivty:

```
public void setData(){
        fetchedData = getIntent().getExtras().get("sentData").toString();
        Cursor data = myDb.setData(fetchedData);
        editTextnumber.setText(data.getString(1));
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME+ " WHERE " + NUMBER + "= ?", new String[] {id});
```

When I setText my fetchedData it's totally fine. Any Help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I've already solved it. I should have used if(data.moveToFirst()) first before setting my text.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setData(){
        fetchedData = getIntent().getExtras().get("sentData").toString();
        Cursor data = myDb.setData(fetchedData);
        if(data.moveToFirst()) {

            editTextnumber.setText(data.getString(1));
            editTextname.setText(data.getString(2));
            editTextaddress.setText(data.getString(5));
            editTextnotes.setText(data.getString(6));
        }
    }
```